# UILabel subclassed and intrinsicContentSize with UIEdgeInsets truncating my text

Tags: swift, uilabel

Here's my subclass :

```
class LabelWithBlackBackGround: UILabel {
var topInset = CGFloat(3)
var bottomInset = CGFloat(3)
var leftInset = CGFloat(15)
var rightInset = CGFloat(10)

override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
    let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
    super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
}

override public var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {

    var intrinsicSuperViewContentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
    intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.height += topInset + bottomInset
    intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.width += leftInset + rightInset
    return intrinsicSuperViewContentSize
}

deinit {
}
}
```

Problem is, when I have multiple lines, a lot of times it's truncating my text, like so :

[image]

It's probably my intrinsicContentSize that is not right, but I can't find what's wrong with it.

Of course, I tried with those :

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```